# How to append link dynamically in table row

Tags: javascript, jquery

Need to append rows with button inside a td cell.
Here is my code:

```
$('#contact_table').find('tbody').append(
                "<tr><td>--</td><td>"+key+"</td><td>"+value+'</td><td><a cal-id=cal-clear class="badge badge-outline-secondary" href="javascript:;"><i class="ti-trash p-1"> </i> delete</a></td></tr>');
```

Has seen similar question of Ben Davidow, my code has similar structure but button('') not appear in a table. No error in console. Why it not working properly?

Comment: Plz include the complete code.

Comment: Make a variable for whatever you want to append, and call that variable inside the append. I'm not sure if it's gonna work or not, but it just came to my mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an issue that your html string is started with double quote and ending with single quote which doesn't sums up.
Anyways, I've modified your code to use interpolation and made it more readable.

Please have a look.

```
const key="key";
const value="value";

$('#contact_table tbody').append(`
    <tr>
        <td>--</td>
        <td>${key}</td>
        <td>${value}</td>
        <td>
            <a cal-id=cal-clear class="badge badge-outline-secondary" href="javascript:;">
                <i class="ti-trash p-1"> </i> delete
            </a>
        </td>
    </tr>
`);
```

Answer (score 0):

has found the issue, code this appending rows must work twice $('tr').click  AND  $("#add_knt" ).click, i has made changes in #add_knt and forgot to do the same to 1 case and testing only first case (uploading from ajax).